# IE10 raises console on Shift+F12 hold. How to prevent?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

This is my preventer:

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            //Shift+F12
            case 123:
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                break;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

This works if I press Shift+F12 once. But if I hold Shift+F12, than the console starts to blink.

I don't need to prevent the console completely. User must be able to raise it, if F12 is pressed. Only Shift+F12 must be protected.

Important to say that other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) don't need this preventer at all. If I hold Shift+F12 in these browsers, than console will never be raised.

Comment: What is your rationale behind doing this?

Comment: @ComFreek, I need to implement my own actions on Shift+F12, but the console that blinks in IE10 looks awful.

Comment: Is it just IE 10 where you have this issue? Your code seems to work fine in IE 11.

Comment: @aquinas, Yes. I saw it only in IE10.